# Output from cmd to wxpython gui

Tags: python, wxpython, scapy

I have a problem, i am sniffing with scapy using python but the result return in the command promp and i need to insert it into a wxpython grid.
how can i make the output from the cmd appear in the grid?

```
from scapy.all import *
packetCount = 0
def customAction(packet):
    global packetCount
    packetCount += 1
    return "Packet #" + str(packetCount) + ": " + packet[0][1].src + "==>" + packet[0][1].dst
sniff(filter="ip",prn=customAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a thread to run Scapy and pass its information back to your UI using a thread-safe method such as `wx.CallAfter` or `wx.PostEvent`. Then in whatever method you call, you can use the grid's methods to insert the data into whichever cell(s) you need to. You can use its `SetCellValue` method, for example.